# Spherical Coordinates from a non centered location

Tags: opencv, geometry, projective-geometry

Assuming a pinhole camera centered at (cx,cy,cz) != (0,0,0) is there a more efficient way to compute it's projection in a spherical coordinate system centered at the origin other than performing a ray-sphere intersection for each pixel?

If the camera was centered at the origin the trivial solution would be:

```
theta = arccos(y/r)
phi = arctan2(x,z)
```